# Extracting from remote JSON

Tags: php, json, extract

I have the JSON url: http://www.lfsworld.net/pubstat/get_stat2.php?version=1.5&idk=5GvgiUmwdVfkZXQdoKOK0aN5LTOzS9Yo&action=hosts&s=1

I am looking to get a certain line where "hostname" is equal to $host, and to then get the value of the "nrracers".

I have the below so far that will just get me the whole file in a different form.

```
<?php
$host = "Random Host Name";
$json = file_get_contents("http://www.lfsworld.net/pubstat/get_stat2.php?version=1.5&idk=5GvgiUmwdVfkZXQdoKOK0aN5LTOzS9Yo&action=hosts&s=1");

var_dump(json_decode($json));
var_dump(json_decode($json, true));
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop its content and compare to the value you want like this:

```
foreach($json as $jsonLine) {
    if($json['hostname'] == $host) {
        doSomething();
        break;
    }
}
```